# Unhide NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

Is there a way to check if the window is hidden and unhide the NSWindow programatically?

I have tried [self showWindow:nil] and [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self] but they cause wierd behaviors like, two windows etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `- (BOOL) isVisible` (so BOOL visible = [self.window isVisible] to dertimine whether a window is hidden or not, and if you want to hide or unhide a window use this:
`[self.window setHidden:YES]` 
And, obviously, you pass NO to unhide it.

**Edit**

Sorry, instead of the  `setHidden` method use the `- (void) setIsVisible:(BOOL) yourBOOL` method.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks! NSWindow has no setHidden method or hidden property. Its NSView's property.